# Doсker is only available after a reboot docker.socket

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, systemd

Based on [Thinstation](https://github.com/Thinstation/thinstation/issues/724#issuecomment-1145661838), I built an `iso` with a `docker` package. The problem is that after raising the service, the connection to the host over the network is available only if restart `docker.socket`. How can I diagnose docker to understand why by default, without restarting the service, there is no possibility of remote connection to the host over the network?

Here is the service log:

```bash
-- Logs begin at Sat 2022-06-04 06:44:32 PDT, end at Sat 2022-06-04 06:44:45 PDT. --
Jun 04 06:44:39 thinstation-linux systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.146186290-07:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.147352611-07:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=3130
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.147385993-07:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.147399661-07:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.147446573-07:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.147473357-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45-07:00" level=warning msg="deprecated version : `1`, please switch to version `2`"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.173591406-07:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16 version=v1.6.4
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.199975908-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.200078325-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201561989-07:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.119TS\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201609700-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201738040-07:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (rootfs) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201769872-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201791635-07:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201809462-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.201863240-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202132975-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202304778-07:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202343950-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202388411-07:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202419790-07:00" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202662008-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202696415-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.exchange\"..." type=io.containerd.event.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202717498-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202759330-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202783160-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202805065-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202840054-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.202875755-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203282487-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203309113-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203330056-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203351267-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203471409-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.203573569-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups\"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205104698-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205208659-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205286555-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.restart\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205403958-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205491828-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205568653-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205648226-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.events\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205719790-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205789802-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.images\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205858833-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.205934557-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.206015063-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.opt\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.206175458-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.209389255-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.209569204-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.version\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.209670052-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.209832522-07:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.209912037-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.210113358-07:00" level=error msg="failed to initialize a tracing processor \"otlp\"" error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.211156374-07:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.211531426-07:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.211662344-07:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[3130]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.211736920-07:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.038934s"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.225142806-07:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.225280438-07:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.225384775-07:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.225519679-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.229535732-07:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.229567923-07:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.229606224-07:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.229623973-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.249833626-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.366721376-07:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.470044352-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.481283885-07:00" level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: kernel has CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_REDIRECT_DIR enabled" storage-driver=overlay2
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.481634808-07:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=f756502 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.16
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.481778501-07:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 04 06:44:45 ts_080027b3b812 dockerd[2349]: time="2022-06-04T06:44:45.512160761-07:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```